# Programmatically selecting ng-options bound to object data source

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I have an ng-options select bound to an object.  Setting the ng-model programmatically only works properly (updates the select) when setting it as a string.  If I set the ng-model as an integer, it doesn't work.  I really don't want to have to make this conversion.  Is this the only way?

http://jsfiddle.net/HMjnV/1/

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select ng-options="id as name for (id, name) in items" ng-model="selected"></select>
    <div>Selected ID: {{selected}} </div>
    <button ng-click="setSelected(1)">Set Selected to ID 1 as Integer</button>
    <button ng-click="setSelected('1')">Set Selected to ID 1 as String</button>
    <div>Programmatically setting the ng-model as string sets the dropdown but not as integer.</div>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.items = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3:'c'};
    $scope.selected = null;

    $scope.setSelected = function(id) {
        $scope.selected = id; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDITED**

You might try using `toString` when you programmatically set the model value, if you're looking for a quick and dirty solution. See @ExpertSystems answer for detail on the core of the problem.

```
$scope.setSelected = function(id) {
    $scope.selected = id.toString(); 
}
```

Comment: Your answer claimed that you can use `ngOptions` to bind only to string values and you linked to the docs where is says you should use `ngOptions` _"when you want the select model to be bound to a non-string value."_. I did provide an answer explaining the problem (if I had more info on what the actual requirements and constraints of the OP, I would provide an appropriate solution).

Comment: I like this approach.  I just made a slight modification to set $scope.selected = String(id);

Answer (score 3):

This is odd, but you *can* get the binding between `ng-options` and `ng-model` to work by forcing a cast to occur in the comprehension expression:

```
ng-options="id*1 as name for (id, name) in items"
```

Here is a fork of your fiddle demonstrating this trick: http://jsfiddle.net/wittwerj/HMjnV/9/

Having said that, I do prefer Marc's approach of converting toString in the controller.

Comment: ... one of the many reasons to love (or hate) javascript on display here. Just multiply a string by 1 to get a number.

Answer (score 2):

Yes to pre-populate the value like you have done then definitely it should be a `string`. Since the value attribute in `option` tag takes only `String`. But yes in **AngularJs** you can give references like this given in the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qWzTb/)** . And the workaround to your problem will be converting id to string.

Comment: Works for my case. It was sufficient to make `$scope.selectedItem[item._id] = {};` in my case. This is my binding directive: `ng-model="selectedItem[item._id]"` where `item` comes from options binding directive `ng-options="item.name for item in items"`.

Answer (score 0):

JS **[Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)** have property name-value pairs.
`value` can be of any type, but `name` is always a string.
Although you think you define it as a number, it is automatically converted to string. 
There is no way you can change that (i.e. create an object with number property-names).